# how to integrate spinner page with rest of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a project where I am creating a spinner page but I am having difficulty integrating the spinner page while I am redirecting to a URL. Basically I have a multiplication program. If the answer is correct it prompts correct and goes to a specific URL(http://stackoverflow.com) and if is incorrect it goes to another URL(http://yahoo.com). Before it actually goes to those pages I would like the spinner that I created to show up first while the pages are loading. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my main HTML page(index1.html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>A Multiplication Game</title>
    </head>

    **<script>
    window.addEventListener("loader", function(){
    var spinner=document.getElementById("spinner");
    document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
    });
    </script>**

    <body >
    <span id="mathprompt">What is <span id="num1">8</span> multiplied by 
    <span id="num2">E</span>?
    </span>
    <br>
    <span id="inputrow">
        <input type="text" id="inputfield">
        <button id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
    </span>

   **<div class="loader" id="spinner"></div>**

   <p id="response"></p>

   <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Here is my JavaScript code(script.js). As you can see I have declared spinner as a variable but not sure if I should right the function for it here or in HTML:

```
 var num1;
 var num2;
 var guess;
 var answer;
 var response;

 $(document).ready(function() {
 num1=document.getElementById("num1");
 num2=document.getElementById("num2");
 guess=document.getElementById("inputfield");
 response=document.getElementById("response");
 **spinner=document.getElementById("spinner");**

 $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
    checkAnswer();
    redirectPage();

 });

 setNumbers();
 });

 function setNumbers(){
 num1.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;
 num2.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;
 }

 function checkAnswer(){
 var n1 = parseInt(num1.innerHTML);
 var n2 = parseInt(num2.innerHTML);
 answer = n1 * n2; 

 if (parseInt(guess.value) == answer){
    response.innerHTML = "Correct!";
 } else
    response.innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
 }

 function redirectPage(){
    if (parseInt(guess.value) == answer){
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    } else{
    window.location.href = "http://yahoo.com";
    }
  }
```

And here is the code for the spinner in the css(stylesheet.css):

```
    @charset "ISO-8859-1";

  #inputrow{
  background-color:#80ff80;
  }

 #mathprompt{
 font-size: 34px;
 color:orange;
 text-align: center;
 }

 #response{
 font-size: 34px;
 color:white;
 text-align: center;
 }

 body {
 background-color: #8080c0;
 text-align: center;
 }

**.loader{
    border:16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; 
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
  }
    @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
 }**
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to happen ... you want the message "Correct!" to display briefly, and then forward the user to a different URL? If so, you can put a setTimeout(...) around your window.location.href statements.

Comment: @emmzee I am just basically trying to figure out of how to put the spinner page before forwarding to a different URL. So instead of setting a timeout, I want that spinner to spin until the page(yahoo or stackoverflow) are fully loaded. I just put this code together for that purpose alone. I know this is not a real life example.

Comment: AFAIK if you want a smooth transition between pages (ie, spinner appears on page 1, then page 2 loads, then spinner disappears), rather than changing pages you will need to load the second page via AJAX (so that the visitor stays on the same page and just the content changes). Otherwise even if you show the spinner, and switch to a second page that also shows the spinner, there will be a gap between when the pages change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to detect that an external website is loaded...you cannot detect this, in Javascript you won't have access to the "loaded" event of an external website loaded in a new tab of your browser.

All your can do is display a loading, then doing a "redirect" in javascript.
And when yahoo/stackoverflow page will be loaded (having replaced your website in the browser tab), your loader will obviously have disappeared...is it what you want ?

**You have 3 cases :**

- If you load yahoo/stackoverflow in an iframe embedded in your page, yes you could display a loading and detect that the page is loaded in your iframe (for instance you load a page of your own in the iframe, you can in JS access to the page's content...you load Yahoo/Stackoverflow in the iframe, then when in JS you cannot access to iframe content, it means that the external page is loaded...)
- if you are redirecting to the yahoo/stackoverflow page, you will only be able to display a loading before the external pages are beginning to load...
- you can try to prefetch the external page, you display a loading, and when the page is loaded, then you redirect to the page...your browser will have cached almost all html elements i think (to check)...

  ```
  var myPrefetchedPage;
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      myPrefetchedPage = html;
    }
  })
  ```

**Preloading code in an iframe** :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $app = $('.app');
    $app.addClass('loading');

    $iframe = $('<iframe>');
    $iframe.attr({src: 'http://www.yahoo.fr/'});
    $iframe.appendTo($('body'));

    // When <iframe> has been loaded, remove loading spinner to reveal <iframe> 
    // or redirect to the page in your browser tab.
    $iframe.load(function() {
        $('.app').remove();
        // redirect to the real page
        window.location.href='http://www.yahoo.fr/';
    });
});
```

Comment: Let me try the iframe method now.

Comment: So i dove in to iframes and went on a google frenzy to see how i can use it but get a bit lost. I am now going to try the second code you have for jquery and see what happens.

Comment: so I tried the jquery method and I get a frame in the middle of my page that cannot load. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: I get this error in the frame:  
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

Comment: But when I click the link they provide to open in a new window I can get to yahoo

Comment: #Pierre So I have a question here. I have my spinner in a page called index2.html. In the code you have provided for jquery, where would I place that html?

Comment: Seems that yahoo doesn't allow iframe embedding. You can put your spinner code in the <div class="app" > ÷ change my. loading with your .loader class...

Comment: (For the spinners, you have also many websites that generate for your a ready to use spinner)